# First order non-linear non-homogenous ode

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve this:
$$v(x)^2\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=gx-v(x)^2$$
(where $g$ is a constant)

Also, is there any general method for dealing with these kind of non-linear non-homogenous equations?

Comment: This is not a linear differential equation, hence there is no "homogeneous" solution etc.

Comment: And it's not of second order but a first order non linear DE

Comment: This is a Chini-equation, for which in general no closed form solution exists. See for example this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt

Comment: @Marco By any chance on RHS it is $v^3$ instead of $v^2$.