# A nonlinear ODE: $ y^2y'=\sin x-y^3,~ y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Non-linear(NL) ODEs are interesting, yet they are chancy and dicy when it comes to solve them.
Recently, one NL ODE at MSE 
[First order non-linear non-homogenous ode](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584201/first-order-non-linear-non-homogenous-ode)
may  be rendered as not-doable and it has been commented to be of the type of Chini equation
that is known to be not-doable. However, here propose a similar NLODE:
$$ y^2y'=\sin x-y^3,~~ y(0)=0$$ to be solved by hand?

Comment: You can substitute $u=y^3 \implies u'=3y^2y'$

Comment: WolframAlpha concluded that there is no solution, at least not satisfying y'(0) = 0.

Comment: Without the condition, $y'(0) = 0$, WolframAlpha gives [this solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dy%2Fdx+%3D+%28sin%28x%29+-+y%5E3%29%2Fy%5E2).

Comment: @VVejalla  it has a solution here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27y%5E2+%3D+%28sin%28x%29+-+y%5E3%29

Comment: Sorry, it should be $y(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y^2y'=\sin x-y^3$$
Substitute $u=y^3$
$$\frac 13 u'+u=\sin x $$
$$ (ue^{3x})'=3e^{3x}\sin x $$
$$ u=3 e^{-3x}\underbrace {\int e^{3x}\sin x dx }_{=I}$$
It's not hard to integrate.
$$ I= \frac 3{10} {e^{3x}}  (\sin x -\frac 13 \cos x)+C$$
$$ u(x)= \frac 9{10}   (\sin x -\frac 13 \cos x)+Ce^{-3x}$$
$$y(0)=0 \implies C=\frac 3 {10}$$